# Background images in <a> tag inside <li> tag not dissapears in IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, list, anchor, background-image

In IE7 and in IE6, I have an anchor inside of an li which has a background image in it. When you mouse over these links, the backagound images go missing in these browsers. Any ideas as to why this would happen?

[Here's an example (IE7 and IE6).](http://alt.mychoicecarinsurance.ca/Reality-Check.aspx)

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

Have you styled the a:hover with the same background image? Just put the image in all psuedo classes:
a:link, a:visited, a:active and a:hover

Comment: Just remember to keep the pseudo-classes in the correct order: :link, :visited, :hover, and :active (LoVe HAte) to make sure they work. Also worth noting that if you style with :hover then similar style rules should be applied to :focus to ensure keyboard access gives the user a similar experience to the mouse.